# Diagnose frozen application

Tags: java, debugging

I have a GUI component that freezes my Java desktop application after a few hours if I leave it open. It looks like a deadlock, probably involving the [Event Dispatching Thread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_dispatching_thread).

I have tried running jconsole, jstack and jvisualvm once the application is frozen to analyse the thread dump but all 3 fail (giving various exceptions that come down to "could not connect to the process").

**Is there another way to diagnose a frozen application and find out what's going on?**

ps: for information, the GUI component is a Java FX 2 table embedded in a Swing panel - it opens fine, reacts well to various interactions, can be closed, but freezes the application after some time.

Comment: Have you attached jconsole prior to the freeze? Monitoring the app prior to the crash may by your only option to get useful info. I'd consider reporting this as a jstack/jconsole/jvisualvm bugs. You may get some good troubleshooting tips from the developers of same or an explanation of the "could not connect to the process" exceptions.

Comment: No I haven't - will try now and report back when... well, we'll see when it crashes!

Comment: @Rob Attaching jvisualvm before the crash did the trick - feel free to post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach jconsole prior to the freeze.

Monitoring the app prior to the crash may be your only option to get useful info.

I'd consider reporting this as jstack/jconsole/jvisualvm bugs. You may get some good troubleshooting tips from the developers of same or an explanation of the "could not connect to the process" exceptions.